# What is the difference between 預金 and 入金?

Tags: pragmatics

Both 預金{よきん} and 入金{にゅうきん} can mean **deposit**. Is there any difference in the usage of these terms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

入金 is a suru-verb that refers to the individual transactions of putting money into a bank account. The antonym is 出金. In daily conversations (お金を)預ける or (お金を)入れる might be more common.

預金 usually refers to the money (already) in an account. It occasionally works as a suru-verb, but when it does, it refers to the long-term state of having money in a bank account.

In other words, if you do 入金, your 預金 will increase.

Answer (score 3):

入金する means "put money into **a** bank account" (as 入 means "put in") and 預金する means "put money into **your own** bank account" ([預](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/4172/meaning/m0u/) means "leave something to be kept"). Thus you can 入金 into your account or your eBay exhibitor's (in another word, 振り込む "transfer"), but only able to 預金 to your own one.

In noun form, 預金 tends to refer to "deposit(ed money)", while 入金 only stands for "(act of) depositing".

Answer (score -1):

> Difference between 預金 and 入金

Both of them have the same meaning of deposit.

Literally, you have to 入金する in order to 預金する.